# how to generate json-arrays with multiple types with jersey/jackson

Tags: javascript, json, jersey, google-visualization

i am trying to generate data for google charts with jersey but i don't know how to create a json array like this:

```
[
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Memory', 80],
    ['CPU', 55],
    ['Network', 68]
]
```

arrays with a single type (1st line) are working but i don't know how to create arrays with multiple types like ['Memory',80]. i tried jersey without and with jackson but every time i try to generate an arraylist with multiple data-types i get something like this:

```
[
  {
    "type" : "xs:string",
    "$" : "Memory"
  }, {
    "type" : "xs:int",
    "$" : "80"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var array = [
  {
    "type" : "xs:string",
    "$" : "Memory"
  }, {
    "type" : "xs:int",
    "$" : "80"
  }
];
//the output array
var translated = [];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i+=2){
     translated.push([array[i]["$"],array[i+1]["$"]]);
}
```

EDIT: If you need a number instead of a string

```
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i+=2){
   var value = array[i+1]["$"];
   //parse to number
   if (/^([0-9])*[.]?[0-9]*$/.test(value)){
       value = value.parseFloat(value);
   }
   translated.push([array[i]["$"],value);
}
```

Comment: if i use your approach i get this:
[["Label", "Value"], ["Memory", "80"], ["CPU", "45"], ["Network", "34"]].
but it has to look like this to get correctly processed by google charts api:
[["Label", "Value"], ["Memory", 80], ["CPU", 45], ["Network", 34]]. (arrays copied form firebug-output)

Comment: I edited my post to parse the string into a number, i hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In our application we are using the JsonSerializer-feature. You design you object in java like you want and than let the serializer do the rest for you.
There you have the "full" control how to do it.

Have a look at our code and add another jgen.writeStartArray() -> jgen.writeEndArray();

```
public class FolderChildrenSerializer extends JsonSerializer<FolderChildren> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(FolderChildren folderchildren, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartArray();
        for (Item i : folderchildren.getList()) {
            jgen.writeObject(i);
        }
        jgen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```